# trouble with geb test click and dragging a slider

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geb

New to geb and automated testing in general. I'm having trouble with automating the ability to click and drag an element on the page. I've read through the book of geb and discovered the Action class and have written some code that is extremely procedural just to test it out. I may be misunderstanding how the action class operates because it it doesn't appear to be performing the task. It compiles with no issues and the test still runs without throwing any errors. The web-element that I'm trying to drag does exist and I'm sure its the correct one.

```
<div id="enquireForm:j_id_t_3_1_u:sliderframe" class="ets-nicecaptcha-slider ets-nicecaptcha-button-style ui-button-gradient">
   <span id="enquireForm:j_id_t_3_1_u:slidedrop" class="ets-nicecaptcha-drop ets-nicecaptcha-button-style ui-droppable">
   </span>
   <div id="enquireForm:j_id_t_3_1_u:sliderbutton" class="ets-nicecaptcha-slider-button ets-nicecaptcha-button-style ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative;">
   </div>
</div>

void slideToSubmit(){
    WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.className("ets-nicecaptcha-slider-button"))
    Actions action = new Actions(driver)
    action.perform()
    action = action.clickAndHold(slider)
    action.perform()
    action = action.moveByOffset(500,0)
    action.perform()
    action = action.release(slider)
    action.perform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The space in the class name may be the issue. Try

```
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='ets-nicecaptcha-slider-button ets-nicecaptcha-button-style ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle']"))
```

or try directly without using `By` class

```
    def browser = new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver()) // or whichever driver you use
    browser.go "www.url.com"
    browser.$("div.ets-nicecaptcha-slider-button.ets-nicecaptcha-button-style.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Geb then you should be using the [`interact()` method](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#interact-closures) which simplifies things like this greatly:

```
interact {
    clickAndHold($(".ets-nicecaptcha-slider-button"))
    moveByOffset(500,0)
    release()
}
```